# How to plot frequency response of butterworth filter using Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, filtering, frequency

I am trying to plot the frequency response of my sequence when filtered by a butterworth, low-pass filter. I have my pole and zero plot figured out just fine but can't seem to get my frequency response plotted correctly. When I do my axis are always way out of scale. I've tried using Matlab's `bode` function to no avail. A sample input that I have been using would be something like this `buttdes(1000, 2500, -3, -20, 20000)`. Any help is much appreciated!! Here is my code so far :

```
function buttdes(fpass, fstop, dp, ds, fs)

%// Design a discrete-time Butterworth filter

%// BUTTDES(fpass, fstop, dp, ds, fs) designs and plots the bode plot

%// of the resulting analog-equivalent filter that has been

%// designed to match the analog parameters fpass (in Hz),

%// fstop (in Hz), dp (in dB) and ds (in dB).

%// fs is the sample rate in Hz

wp = fpass/fs;        
ws = fstop/fs;
WpT = 2 * tan(wp / 2);
WsT = 2 * tan(ws / 2);
qp = log10(10^-(dp/10)-1);
qs = log10(10^-(ds/10)-1);

N = ceil((qs-qp) / 2 / log10(WsT / WpT)); 
WcT = WpT * 10^(-qp/2/N);

k = 0:N-1;
skT = WcT * exp(j*pi*(2*k+N+1)/2/N);

b = real(prod(skT./(skT -2))) * poly(-ones(1, N));
a = real(poly(-(skT+2)./(skT-2)));

zplane(b, a);
```

Comment: @Benoit_11 zplane is my pole-zero plot.

Comment: Probably this function: http://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/zplane.html

Comment: How did you try plotting frequency response? freqz(b,a) works fine.

Comment: @Navan Sorry for the late response. I tried using freq. but my axis were still not getting formatted right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the comment by Navan, you can use the `freqz` command to compute and plot the frequency response of the filter.  `freqz` is in the Signal Processing Toolbox, so if you don't have that toolbox, you'll need another method.

`freqz` normally makes two plots: (1) one plot of the amplitude response and (2) one plot of the phase response.  If you just want the amplitude response, you can plot it like this

```
%compute the filter response
npoints = 1000;  %how many points to you want?   
[h,f]=freqz(b,a,npoints,fs);
response_dB = 10.*log10(h.*conj(h));
response_deg = 180/pi*angle(h);

% make plot
figure;
semilogx(f,response_dB);
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Response (dB)');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I realize that I was not using freqz correctly. I didn't realize i needed a separate variable to plot the response in the dB scale. This is really helpful! Thanks again!

Comment: How do you plot phase?